# Show ProximityPrompt only with item held?

Tags: lua, roblox

I would like to make a proximity prompt on an NPC but I only want it to show up when the player is holding a certain item. Does anyone know how?

Comment: By only listening to the proximity prompt if the player holds that item. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Make a LocalScript on a Tool that enables the ProximityPrompt. Or have a LocalScript that observes the player's backpack and enables the Prompt when the object is acquired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code for you. This code listens for the opening of an item, and then creates a proximity prompt at the desired location of the NPC.
Then, it listens for the unequipping and removes the prompt. Be sure to change the name of the NPC in line 1 to the name/location of yours.Put this as a serverscript as a child to the tool.

```lua
local npc = Workspace:WaitForChild("NPC")
local HumanoidRootPartPos = npc:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").Position
local tool = script.Parent

tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
     local ProximityPrompt = Instance.new("ProximityPrompt")
     ProximityPrompt.Position = HumanoidRootPartPos
     ProximityPrompt.Parent = npc
     ProximityPrompt.Name  = "ToolInteractionPrompt"
     --configure the action text and prompt text here (i forgot the property names)
end)

tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
     local prompt = npc:FindFirstChild("ToolInteractionPrompt")
     prompt:Destroy()
end)
```

Comment: When I run the code it says that Position is not a value of proximity prompt.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to add position to the proximity prompt code. Remove that line and try again, it should work.

Comment: Why don't *you* remove that line from your code? You can [edit] your answer.